# Plot confusion matrix for multiple class classifications

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I tried to play with random forest classifier and need to construct confusion matrix for better understanding of the on how recall and precision look like in large dataset. I'm working classify the order or animals with 6 columns of features selected from the particular dataset and 1 column of order of which the animal belong.

since there a lot of orders in the column it i assume the confusion matrix would be ambiguous and complex.

how to plot the confusion matrix for each order that the animals belong ?

my confusion matrix

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()

x_training, x_testing, y_training,y_testing = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.26,shuffle=True, random_state=None)#70%training 
classifier.fit(x_training,y_training.values.ravel())
print("training set ",x_training.shape, "with result ",y_testing.shape)

y_predict = classifier.predict(x_testing)

print(classifier.score(x_testing,y_testing))
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
mtx = (metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_testing,y_predict))
print(mtx)
[[[342   1]
  [  0   8]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[348   0]
  [  0   3]]

 [[349   0]
  [  0   2]]

 [[299   2]
  [  1  49]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[304   0]
  [  1  46]]

 [[346   0]
  [  1   4]]

 [[345   0]
  [  3   3]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[349   0]
  [  1   1]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[340   1]
  [  0  10]]

 [[348   0]
  [  0   3]]

 [[348   2]
  [  0   1]]

 [[349   0]
  [  2   0]]

 [[339   2]
  [  0  10]]

 [[347   0]
  [  2   2]]

 [[347   0]
  [  0   4]]

 [[350   1]
  [  0   0]]

 [[345   0]
  [  0   6]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[349   0]
  [  0   2]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[334   4]
  [  2  11]]

 [[342   1]
  [  1   7]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[345   2]
  [  0   4]]

 [[349   0]
  [  0   2]]

 [[349   1]
  [  1   0]]

 [[345   2]
  [  2   2]]

 [[312   1]
  [  3  35]]

 [[347   1]
  [  0   3]]

 [[350   0]
  [  0   1]]

 [[343   0]
  [  1   7]]

 [[301   9]
  [  4  37]]

 [[350   0]
  [  1   0]]

 [[345   2]
  [  0   4]]

 [[314   0]
  [  1  36]]

 [[349   0]
  [  1   1]]

 [[350   1]
  [  0   0]]

 [[342   0]
  [  0   9]]]
```

then my y_testing

```
print(y_testing)
                Order
338     Diprotodontia
8           Carnivora
458          Primates
1134  Charadriiformes
959          Squamata
              ...
354     Diprotodontia
745          Primates
362          Rodentia
731          Rodentia
533          Primates
```

I tries to print the report of recall, precision, f1 score

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_testing,y_predict))

precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Accipitriformes       0.89      1.00      0.94         8
       Afrosoricida       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
       Anseriformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
        Apodiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
       Artiodactyla       0.96      0.98      0.97        50
     Bucerotiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
   Caprimulgiformes       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
          Carnivora       1.00      0.98      0.99        47
    Charadriiformes       1.00      0.80      0.89         5
         Chiroptera       1.00      0.50      0.67         6
      Ciconiiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
          Cingulata       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      Columbiformes       1.00      0.50      0.67         2
      Coraciiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
         Crocodilia       0.91      1.00      0.95        10
     Dasyuromorphia       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
         Dermoptera       0.33      1.00      0.50         1
    Didelphimorphia       0.00      0.00      0.00         2
      Diprotodontia       0.83      1.00      0.91        10
       Eulipotyphla       1.00      0.50      0.67         4
      Falconiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
        Galliformes       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
         Gruiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         6
         Hyracoidea       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
         Lagomorpha       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
  Opisthocomiformes       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
        Otidiformes       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      Passeriformes       0.73      0.85      0.79        13
     Pelecaniformes       0.88      0.88      0.88         8
    Peramelemorphia       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
     Perissodactyla       0.67      1.00      0.80         4
Phoenicopteriformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
          Pholidota       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
             Pilosa       0.50      0.50      0.50         4
           Primates       0.97      0.92      0.95        38
        Proboscidea       0.75      1.00      0.86         3
  Procellariiformes       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
     Psittaciformes       1.00      0.88      0.93         8
           Rodentia       0.80      0.90      0.85        41
         Scandentia       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
    Sphenisciformes       0.67      1.00      0.80         4
           Squamata       1.00      0.97      0.99        37
       Strigiformes       1.00      0.50      0.67         2
   Struthioniformes       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
         Testudines       1.00      1.00      1.00         9

           accuracy                           0.91       351
          macro avg       0.71      0.70      0.69       351
       weighted avg       0.90      0.91      0.90       351
```

next, i tried to plot the confusion matrix blatantly with function

```
def const_confusion_matrix():

    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
    
    titles_options = [("Confusion matrix without normalization", None),
                      ("Normalized confusion matrix", 'true')]

    for title, normalize in titles_options:
        disp = plot_confusion_matrix(classifier, x_testing, y_testing,
                                     display_labels='too many',
                                     #cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                     normalize=normalize)
        disp.ax_.set_title(title)
        
        print(title)
        print(disp.confusion_matrix)
    plt.show()

const_confusion_matrix()
```

the result is

```
Confusion matrix without normalization
[[12  0  0 ...  1  0  0]
 [ 0  7  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 49 ...  0  0  0]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ...  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0 13]]
Normalized confusion matrix
[[0.86 0.   0.   ... 0.07 0.   0.  ]
 [\[0.   1.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  \]
 \[0.   0.   0.94 ... 0.   0.   0.  \]
 ...
 \[0.   0.   0.   ... 0.5  0.   0.  \]][1]
 [0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.93]]
```

with plot

[image: plot of confusion matrix 1]
[image: plot of confusion matrix 2]

is there any approach to plot for each of the confusion matrix or in form of more easy to understand?

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: yeah sorry about  that ,forgot , just how to plot the confusion matrix for each of the order which there are like 40 of them or in more readable form of it. .

Comment: if you have 40 labels.. how else would you want to do it? Maybe makes sense to just plot the precision for each label?

Comment: you can visualize many "one-vs-all" matrices. Or you may not be interested in classes with too low support, e.g. filter out with support <=2 and then draw normal cm